# github php buildpack supporting DB2 and IBM Cloud php app

Tags: php, github, db2, ibm-cloud, buildpack

We have a PHP app on IBM Cloud connected to an instance of DB2 (also on IBM Cloud) that has been working flawlessly for 2 years

Up until Sept 16th, we used the [buildbpack](https://github.com/ibmdb/php-buildpack) with our PHP app (so that it could connect to DB2 via the db2_connect PHP function.)

Now after the `cflinuxfs3` upgrade that buildpack does not work and we are forced to use the

> " "php_buildpack" community buildpack already installed in Cloud Foundry".

however, This new buildpack does not support DB2 connections. When trying to use this buildpack I run a log I find this error :

> "undefined function : db2_connect()".

I've searched high and low for a buildpack that would both support connections to DB2 and be compatible with cflinuxfx3 on IBM Cloud Foundry.

Does anyone know of such a buildpack?

Comment: Show more information about the runtime environment, for example, Show php extensions by running command `php -m`.

Answer (score 1):

There was an announcement:

**Swift Buildpack on IBM Cloud Now Supports cflinuxfs3 and Includes New Runtimes** 
https://www.ibm.com/cloud/blog/announcements/the-swift-buildpack-versions-2020-and-210-are-now-available-on-ibm-cloud

Here is snipped from the URL:

---

The Swift buildpack versions 2.0.20 and 2.1.0 are now available on IBM Cloud.

These buildpacks provide Swift version 5.0 as the default runtime and caches version 4.2.4. An existing application will not be affected by the new buildpack until you redeploy it. After you redeploy, existing applications should continue to run "as is" without any additional changes. New applications will automatically use the new buildpack. Swift buildpack verison 2.1.0 supports cflinuxfs3 only and version 2.0.20 supports cflinuxfs2 only.

---

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you for the effort but those are SWIFT buildpacks and are not compatible with php apps. I need a php buildpack here