# Heroku php buildpack running slow on IBM Cloud Foundry

Tags: heroku, db2, ibm-cloud, buildpack

We have a PHP app on IBM Cloud connected to an instance of DB2 (also on IBM Cloud) that has been working flawlessly for 2 years

Up until Sept 16th, we used the https://github.com/ibmdb/php-buildpack buildbpack with our PHP app (so that it could connect to DB2 via the db2_connect PHP function.)

Now after the cflinuxfs3 upgrade that buildpack does not work and we are forced to use the

" "php_buildpack" community buildpack already installed in Cloud Foundry".

however, This new buildpack does not support DB2 connections. When trying to use this buildpack I run a log I find this error :

"undefined function : db2_connect()".

We are currently using an older buildpack:
https://github.com/ibmdb/db2heroku-buildpack-php
this one DOES support connections to DB2 but it make the app VERY slow. A simple www page will load up to 60 seconds. We used this buildpack up until some 18 months ago, until they changed something on IBM Cloud and the heroku buiildpack staterd working very slow.... and we were told by support to use the one I mentioned at the begining. So, does anyone know WHY the heroku build pack works so slow or better yet is there a way to config your IBM Cloud account so that the heroku buildpack works normally?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [github php buildpack supporting DB2 and IBM Cloud php app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58516899/github-php-buildpack-supporting-db2-and-ibm-cloud-php-app)

Comment: hi @mustaccio ...no. That is a Swift build pack... does not work with php apps